# BERT eval loss increase while performance metrics also increase

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, overfitting, transformers

I want to fine-tune BERT for Named Entity Recognition (NER). However, when fine-tuning over several epochs on different datasets I get a weird behaviour where the training loss decreases, eval loss increases and performance metrics such as F1, accuracy, precision and recall increase. I have tried scripts from different tutorials, but all display this behaviour.

Some sources I have read suggest fine-tuning is a small epochs process, while others report fine-tuning for more than 20 epochs for BERT and NER.

Is this behaviour normal for BERT and NER? What are the best practices for avoiding such behaviour.

Note: If you want to reproduce my results, you can use this [Google Colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lsTTJJAgymED55UXRzxu_T3utxzkqP6M?usp=sharing) from this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@acsariyildiz/named-entity-recognition-with-bert-in-10-steps-6511d4c60d74#dd89). I changed `num_train_epochs` to `30`. `learning_rate` is `5e-5`, although I have tried other similar rates and schedulers but still get similar results.

Thanks!

[image: Train loss]
[image: Eval loss]
[image: Performance metrics]